# I am getting this error while creating a new connection for sqldatasource in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ssl

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM6dI.png)

I also enabled trust server certificate,
also added encrypt = false in my connection string, but the error is persistent

the error is:
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL
Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)